# ¿Cómo ir a una dirección URL al tocar una notificación?

Tags: android-studio, push-notification

Tengo el siguiente codigo para el manejo de una Notificacion, funciona bien, pero ahora necesito hacerle un par de cambios, he intentado un par de cosas pero no me funcionan:

1. Actualmente al tocar la notificacion pasa a otra activity, pero ahora necesito que al tocar la Notificacion pase a una direccion URL (https://elmundodelosninos.org/  ó [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) he intentado cambiando el nombre de la activity actual por la URL, pero no funciona.

Código actual

```
   Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
```

lo he cambinado por:

```
   Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, "https://elmundodelosninos.org/");
```

pero no logro que me funcione.

2. En la linea .setLargeIcon actualmente toma una imagen de la carpeta draware, pero ahora necesito que tome la imagen que esta en una direccion URL.

Código actual

```
   .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.figura1))
```

he intentado de varias formas pero no me funciona

```
   .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), "https://elmundodelosninos.org/imagenes/figura1.jpg"))
   .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource("https://elmundodelosninos.org/imagenes/figura1.jpg")
   .setLargeIcon("https://elmundodelosninos.org/imagenes/figura1.jpg")
```

El codigo completo de la notificacion es

```
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CH_ID")
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.figura1))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.figura2)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(mensaje)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(mensaje))
                    .setColor(Color.BLUE)
                    .setWhen( System.currentTimeMillis() )
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(soundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Abrir una URL al tocar la notificación:**

```java
// ¡Nyaa~! (^・ω・^ )
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://elmundodelosninos.org/imagenes/figura1.jpg"));
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```

2. **Cargar una imagen desde una URL para el ícono grande de la notificación:**

```java
// ¿Quieres una imagen para tu notificación? (´｡• ᵕ •｡`)
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

String imageUrl = "https://elmundodelosninos.org/imagenes/figura1.jpg";

try {
    // Descarga la imagen para tu notificación (*＾▽＾)／
    Bitmap largeIcon = Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).get();
    
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CH_ID")
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            // ¡Personaliza tu notificación! ٩(◕‿◕｡)۶
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.figura2)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(mensaje)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(mensaje))
            .setColor(Color.BLUE)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // ¡Muestra la notificación ahora! ヾ(≧▽≦*)o
    // ...
    // ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Gracias Dev Froggy con lo que me sugeriste ajuste mi código y solucione los dos problemas, gracias

Answer (score 0):

En [la documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases?hl=es-419#open-urls) dice que debes crear un `Intent` con la acción [`ACTION_VIEW`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent?hl=es-419#ACTION_VIEW) y la URL que te interesa abrir.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
```